# Query Very Slow to Run, might need optimisation?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have below code and it took around 10 minutes to run. I could not figure out why though... Any suggestion? Looking up for a month worth of sales which around 51000 lines of transaction.

```
WITH CUSTOMER_SALESTYPE AS (

SELECT CUSTOMER_ID
       ,CUSTOMER_NAME
       ,CASE Sales_type WHEN 'A' THEN 'TRADE'
                       WHEN 'B' THEN 'WHOLESALE'
                       WHEN 'C' THEN 'TRADE'
                       WHEN 'M' THEN 'WHOLESALE'
                       WHEN 'N' THEN 'WHOLESALE'
                       WHEN 'P' THEN 'TRADE'
                       WHEN 'S' THEN 'TRADE'
                       WHEN 'V' THEN 'WHOLESALE' END AS 'SALESTYPE'
       ,CASE B.STATE WHEN 'TAS' THEN 'VIC' ELSE B.STATE END AS 'STATE'
FROM BSIT_ERA_RAW_DATA.DBO.CUSTOMER A
LEFT JOIN BSIT_ERA_RAW_DATA.DBO.TERRITORY_REP B ON A.TERR_CODE = B.TERR_CODE
WHERE BSIT_STORE = 'STORE01'
      AND B.STATE IN ('VIC','QLD','NSW','WA','SA','TAS')

)

SELECT B.STATE
      ,B.SALESTYPE
      ,C.BRAND_NAME
      ,SUM(TOTAL_SALE_AMT) AS 'Net Sales'
      ,SUM(TOTAL_COST) AS 'Net Cost'
      ,SUM(TOTAL_SALE_AMT) - SUM(TOTAL_COST) AS 'Net Margin'
      ,STR(100*((SUM(TOTAL_SALE_AMT) - SUM(TOTAL_COST)) / SUM(TOTAL_SALE_AMT)),5,2) + '%' AS 'Net Margin%'
  FROM [BSIT_ERA_RAW_DATA].[dbo].[PROD_HIST] A
  INNER JOIN CUSTOMER_SALESTYPE B ON A.CUST_NO = B.CUSTOMER_ID
  INNER JOIN BSIT_ERA_RAW_DATA.dbo.DIM_PART C ON RIGHT(A.PART_NO,LEN(A.PART_NO)-2) = C.PART_NO
  WHERE TRANS_DATE >= DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, GETDATE()) - 1, 0) 
        AND TRANS_DATE < DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, GETDATE()) , 0)
        AND TRANS_TYPE IN ('SLS', 'CM') 
        AND INVOICE_NO IS NOT NULL
        AND A.TRANS_CODE != 'L'
        AND A.TRANS_CODE != 'PL'
        OR
        TRANS_DATE >= DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, GETDATE()) - 1, 0) 
        AND TRANS_DATE < DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, GETDATE()) , 0) 
        AND TRANS_TYPE IN ('SLS', 'CM') 
        AND INVOICE_NO IS NOT NULL
        AND A.TRANS_CODE IS NULL
  GROUP BY B.STATE
          ,B.SALESTYPE
          ,C.BRAND_NAME
```

Comment: 1. check execution plan and 2. use index suggested by execution plan or create, 3. if you are in production use NOLOCK

Comment: 1. Are you sure you are getting the correct result? Normally you need to enclose `OR` terms in appropriate brackets. 2. You're doing a left join on territory rep then your filtering it which makes it an inner join. 3. Indexes - do you have any?

Comment: Why use LEFT JOIN in CUSTOMER_SALESTYPE when you use in WHERE condition this: AND B.STATE IN ('VIC','QLD','NSW','WA','SA','TAS'). Replace with INNER JOIN